# Why does 'DD/MM/YYYY' not work in filters?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Why do either of the below not work?

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(date '23/08/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY')

SELECT date_trunc('w', date '28/10/2020')
```

But if I do e.g. `SELECT date_trunc('w', date '10/28/2020')` it does work. I guess it's to do with the way I wrote the date in Redshift? What is the explanation behind this?

Comment: It is not valid SQL.  What are you attempting to do?  Perhaps an `=` is needed.

Comment: Sorry I updated to make it clearer.

Comment: This non-standard date literal seems to be parsed using the MM/DD/YYYY pattern, while you expect DD/MM/YYYY. FYI, the SQL standard only specifies date literals with YYYY-MM-DD pattern.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the reply. I am not sure I follow what you are saying fully. Are you saying we can't use DD/MM/YYYY in SELECT or WHERE in redshift? It always has to be of form MM/DD/YYYY?

Answer (score 2):

The pattern says the **MONTH** goes first, but the test value clearly has the **DAY** first. You need the pattern to match your data. If the string in the question is typical of your data, you want this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(date '23/08/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: My understanding was that the TO_CHAR function is of the form TO_CHAR (timestamp_expression |'format') where 'format' is the new format? So you specify the format you want and that's the format the result will be in? Is this understanding incorrect?

Comment: Hi Joel, would you be able to clarify on the above?